# Which takes the biggest hit: AnsiString to String or String to AnsiString?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2009

For my purposes, I'm actually truly using ASCII character data (for submitting ASCII text files to the state), so just using unicodestring won't help the end result (I'd still have to convert something).

I've got the option to convert a StrComp function in Delphi 2009 that went from comparing a AnsiString and an PAnsiChar to a UnicodeString and an PAnsiChar.

```
Val : PAnsiChar
Mask : TEditMask;
```

....

this is my original code, it's not good

```
StrComp(PAnsiChar(Mask.EditText), Val);
```

....

so, I can change it to this:

```
StrComp(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(MAskEdit.EditText), Val);
```

or, I can change it to this (extra conversions for 'clarity'):

```
StrComp(PChar(MAskEdit.EditText), PChar(String(AnsiString(Val))));
```

I remember Marco Cantu saying, don't do one of these in a loop, I just don't remember which one or why.

Comment: You could call CompareStringA from kernel32 (get it from Windows.pas) just as the VCL AnsiStrings unit does. Then you have to 1 conversion from  Unicode to Ansi. Is this really a bottleneck?

Comment: What appears to be the biggest problem is when you keep appending to a growing string. Ala `UnicodeStr := ANSIStr + UnicodeStr`.  I just didn't know if that was any easier on the CPU than `ANSISTr := UnicodeStr + AnsiStr`.  It doesn't matter is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Use StringBuilder for that. That problem is about heap allocation. Minimise the conversions. So build the string without conversion and then convert at the final stage.

Comment: Seems like something easy enough to test for yourself. But have you noticed any poor performance such that it's worth the bother of changing your code at all?

Comment: @Rob Haven't gotten through all 292 errors and warnings yet. I'll write the tests myself probably'll answer this myself.

Comment: @David CompareStringA is much slower than StrComp/CompareString and won't return the same values (comparison is more complete using CompareStringA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compile this:

```
StrComp(PAnsiChar(Mask.EditText), Val);
```

There is an implicit conversion from the `Mask.EditText` as `UnicodeString` into a temporary `AnsiString` in order to allow the type cast to `PAnsiChar`. That is your 2nd line:

```
StrComp(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(MAskEdit.EditText), Val);
```

But writing

```
StrComp(PChar(MAskEdit.EditText), PChar(String(AnsiString(Val))));
```

will let `PChar(MAskEdit.EditText)` return a `PChar`, that is a `PWideChar`, so it will use the other overloaded `StrComp` function.

In fact, there are two overloaded functions defined since Delphi 2009 in SysUtils.pas:

```
function StrComp(const Str1, Str2: PAnsiChar): Integer; overload;
function StrComp(const Str1, Str2: PWideChar): Integer; overload;
```

Both functions won't call the windows API, but will compare the characters one by one, with case sensitivity.

So my advice is that you simply do not use any pointer in your code, but rely on plain `string` = `UnicodeString` variables everywhere in your code, and use this function instead:

```
function CompareStr(const S1, S2: string): Integer;
```

The comparison will be the same, and there will be no hidden conversion. The issue with having `WideChar` instead of `AnsiChar` (i.e. having two times more memory) is nothing compared with the conversion (two WinAPI calls) between unicode and current ansi page. To quote your title, conversion direction does not matter: it is always much slower than no conversion.

If you search about speed, I suspect that `Mask.EditText` is definitively the bottleneck in your code. This method will send a GDI message, wait for the response of the component, then affect a `string` with the text. You should better use a temporary variable on stack, if, as I suspect, you are using this `Mask.EditText` expression in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is - why are you comparing a `UnicodeString` to a `PAnsiChar` instead of updating the `PAnsiChar` data to Unicode?  You should use AnsiChar/AnsiString at the boundaries that interact with legacy data, network connections, etc. All internal processing should be using a single string encoding to avoid these kinds of issues.  Convert legacy/network data from Ansi to Unicode when loading the data.  Convert from Unicode to Ansi when saving legacy data, sending network data, etc.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote.  Remy is right: the best behaviour would be to load your data, convert to Unicode (what the rest of the system / RTL / VCL / *everything* uses) and convert back if you must when exporting.  Ie, keep the conversions at the edges of your app.